# Ошибка Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject cannot be cast to org.kxml2.kdom.Node

Tags: android, soap

Программа должна сформировать SOAP запрос по заданому шаблону:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:General.Intf-IGeneral" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><env:Body><ns1:Login env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><UserName xsi:type="xsd:string"></UserName><Password xsi:type="xsd:string"></Password><IP xsi:type="xsd:string"></IP></ns1:Login></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Но на выходе:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="urn:General.Intf-IGeneral" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"><env:Body><n0:Login xmlns:n0=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding""><UserName xsi:type="xsd:string">John</UserName><Password xsi:type="xsd:string">Candy</Password><IP xsi:type="xsd:string">192.168.1.1</IP></n0:Login></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Разница тегов правильного:

```
<ns1:Login env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
```

И неправильного:

```
<n0:Login xmlns:n0="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">
```

Создан класс CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope, где переопределены 2 метода write и writeBody:

```
public class CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope extends SoapSerializationEnvelope{

public final String ns1="urn:General.Intf-IGeneral";
public final String encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding";
public CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope(int version) {
    super(version);
}

@Override
public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
   super.addAdornments=false;
   super.dotNet=false;
    writer.setPrefix("env",env); // <-- changed line
    writer.setPrefix("ns1", ns1 );
    writer.setPrefix("xsd",xsd);
    writer.setPrefix("xsi",xsi);
    writer.setPrefix("enc",enc);

    writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
    writer.startTag(env, "Body");
    writeBody(writer);

    writer.endTag(env, "Body");
    writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
}
public void writeBody(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
    if (encodingStyle != null) {
        writer.attribute(env, "encodingStyle", encodingStyle);
    }
   ((Node) bodyOut).write(writer);
}}
```

При компиляции ошибка:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
>   cannot be cast to org.kxml2.kdom.Node

Сниппет, где формируется пакет и создается запрос:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("UserName","John")
    .addProperty("Password","Candy")
    .addProperty("IP","192.168.1.1");
    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
    CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new  CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope(CustomSoapEnvelop.VER12);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Needed to make the internet call
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
    //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
    SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ((Node) bodyOut).write(writer);

Объект bodyOut не может скаститься в класс `org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject`

Посмотри какому классу принадлежит объект `bodyOut` и поймешь почему эта ошибка получается.

Comment: Я пробую переопределить метод writeBody класса SoapSerializationEnvelope, который в свою очередь расширяет SoapEnvelop. Не понимаю почему в классе-потомке нельзя вызывать обьекты суперкласса.